# Need to restrict a user to check consecutive checkboxes inside each Inner Table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table (id=’MainTable’) where I am displaying availability records and inside the Main Table I have a table with checkboxes for the available time. The checkboxes in the Inner Table will be different in number and there will 1 or more than 1 checkboxes for each record in a table. e.g the Inner Table of first line can have 5 checkboxes and can have 3 checkboxes for the second line and so on.

A user can check 1 or more than 1 checkboxes of a specific line of Inner Table but in a sequence/consecutive to book an assessor for more than 1 hour.

E.g In the first line a user can select either a checkbox with “08:00 AM - 09:00 AM” and “09:00 AM - 10:00 AM” to make 2 hours but can’t select “08:00 AM - 09:00 AM” and “12:00 PM - 01:00 PM” to make 2 hours because they are not consecutive checkboxes.

E.g In the second line a user can select either a checkbox with “09:30 AM - 10:30 AM” and “10:30 AM - 11:30 AM” to make 2 hours but can’t select “09:30 AM - 10:30 AM” and “05:00 PM - 06:00 PM” to make 2 hours because they are not consecutive checkboxes.

I have a different id for the Inner Table

I am only providing HTML of the Inner Table:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" id="Tab_13322918">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td style="font-size:10px;color:brown">
            <input type="checkbox" value="08:00 AM - 09:00 AM"> 08:00 AM - 09:00 AM
        </td>
        <td style="font-size:10px;color:brown">
            <input type="checkbox" value="09:00 AM - 10:00 AM"> 09:00 AM - 10:00 AM
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="font-size:10px;color:brown">
            <input type="checkbox" value="12:00 PM - 01:00 PM"> 12:00 PM - 01:00 PM
        </td>
        <td style="font-size:10px;color:brown">
            <input type="checkbox" value="01:00 PM - 02:00 PM"> 01:00 PM - 02:00 PM
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="font-size:10px;color:brown">
            <input type="checkbox" value="02:00 PM - 03:00 PM"> 02:00 PM - 03:00 PM
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

[image]

Comment: By consecutive checkboxes I mean consecutive times and no gap in between.

Comment: I finally had time to correct my first solution and I also added an example based on time values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always get the index of the first and last checked checkboxes among the checkbox group and ensure that the currently checked checkbox is at position `lastIndex + 1` or `firstIndex - 1`.

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/QkQQc/1/)

Please note that I am using event delegation to avoid adding listeners to every checkboxes, but if you have other checkboxes in your table, you will have to find a way of targetting the right ones only. You could add an additionnal class to all the concerned checkbox and modify the delegate selector accordingly.

```
$('#your-table').on('click', '[type=checkbox]', function (e) {
    var $el = $(e.currentTarget),
        $checkboxes = $el.closest('table').find('[type=checkbox]'),
        $checkedEls = $checkboxes.filter(':checked').filter(function (index, el) {
            return el !== $el[0];
        }),
        elIndex = $checkboxes.index($el),
        firstCheckedIndex = $checkboxes.index($checkedEls.first()),
        lastCheckedIndex = $checkboxes.index($checkedEls.last());

    return !$checkedEls.length
        || (elIndex === firstCheckedIndex - 1 || elIndex === lastCheckedIndex + 1);
});
```

EDIT:

> In your solution I can select "09:00 AM - 10:00 AM" and "12:00 PM -
>   01:00 PM" which I don't want. By consecutive checkboxes I mean
>   consecutive times and no gap in between.

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/QkQQc/2/)

```
$('#your-table').on('click', '[type=checkbox]', function (e) {
    var $el = $(e.currentTarget),
        $checkboxes = $el.closest('table').find('[type=checkbox]'),
        $checkedEls = $checkboxes.filter(':checked').filter(function (index, el) {
            return el !== $el[0];
        }),
        timeParts = $el.val().split(' - ');

    return !$checkedEls.length
        || (
            timeParts[1] === $checkedEls.first().val().split(' - ')[0] 
            || timeParts[0] === $checkedEls.last().val().split(' - ')[1]
        );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First, a big thanks to plalx, who provided an almost perfect answer! However, a few modifications were necessary to make his script run in the end.

I also took the freedom to suggest a slightly different way of handling he result of the check. In my version I simply set all the checkboxes from first to last `:checked` to `prop('checked',true)` by the click-handler, so there will always be a continuous range selected, no matter where the user clicks:

```
$('table[id^=Tab]').on('click', ':checkbox', function (e) {
    var $el   =$(e.currentTarget), // $(this) would also work here ...
        allcb =$el.closest('table').find(':checkbox'),
        firstc=allcb.index(allcb.filter(':checked:first')),
        lastc =allcb.index(allcb.filter(':checked:last'));  
        allcb.slice(firstc,lastc+1).prop('checked',true);
});
```

Feel free to play around with and modify my [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HzGF5/).
I was not quite certain from reading your question of *how many* consecutive checkmarks are actually allowed. My version does not enforce a limit on that, but, of course, that can be introduced too.

**Edit**:

As requested by OP here a more restrictive solution:

```
$('table[id^=Tab]').on('click', ':checkbox', function (e) {
    var $el   =$(e.currentTarget),
        allcb =$el.closest('table').find(':checkbox'),
        firstc=allcb.index(allcb.filter(':checked:first')),
        lastc =allcb.index(allcb.filter(':checked:last'));
    return (lastc-firstc==0) || 
           (allcb.slice(firstc,lastc+1).filter(':checked').length>(lastc-firstc)); 
});
```

Clicks on checkboxes that would cause the sequence of checked boxes to be interrupted are simply ignored by returning `false` in the event handler.

http://jsfiddle.net/HzGF5/6/

Comment: In your solution I can select "09:00 AM - 10:00 AM" and "12:00 PM - 01:00 PM" which I don't want.


By consecutive checkboxes I mean consecutive times and no gap in between.

Comment: @AsifAkhtar I have updated my answer for your needs and also fixed the code of my previous example.